# $n \times n$ invertible matrix defining diffeomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I was reading the proof of the Hairy Ball Theorem in Madsen and Tornehave's book "From calculus to cohomology", and at some point they refer to the Lemma 6.14, which says the following:

*An invertible real $n \times n$ matrix $A$ defines a linear isomorphism $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and a diffeomorphism $f_A : \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$.*

**Lemma 6.14:** *For each $n \geq 2$, the induced map $f_A^\ast: H^{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}) \to H^{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\})$ operates by multiplication by $\det A / |\det A| \in \{\pm 1\}$.*

I understand how the matrix induces a linear isomorphism, but how is the diffeomorphism $f_A$ defined, and why is this assertion true?

Comment: $f_A(x)=Ax{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear isomorphism $f_A: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ given by multiplication by $A$ is a diffeomorphism essentially by definition of the standard smooth structure on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then it is a general fact that a diffeomorphism, when restricted to an open submanifold, is a diffeomorphism onto its image. In this case, the image of $(f_A) \rvert_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}}$ is $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$, so we have an induced diffeomorphism $(f_A) \rvert_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}}:\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$.